# Rails: ordering by most recent sign up

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a scope on my User model that gets users by country

```
scope :canada, where(:country => 'Canada')
```

If someone new signs up they're showing up at the bottom of the list, but I want to put them at the top.  I tried to do this, thinking Rails had some built-in way to change order

```
scope :canada, where(:country => 'Canada').order('DESC')
```

but I got this error message

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: DESC: SELECT "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."country" = 'Canada' ORDER BY DESC
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should specify an actual column name to sort on.

```
# records from Canada should be near the top of the list.
# that is, if you don't have countries that start with A or B. :)
scope :canada, where(:country => 'Canada').order('country ASC')
```

Or maybe you need just to sort on `created_at`

```
# newest records are on top
scope :canada, where(:country => 'Canada').order('created_at DESC')
```

Or, if you want canadian records to be on top, and other records in unspecified order, you can try this:

```
scope :canada, where(:country => 'Canada').order("case when country = 'Canada' then 0 else 1 end")
```

Comment: okay thanks, but it's not actually having the effect I want. No matter if I put DESC or ASC, the latest person to sign up is always showing up at the bottom of the list. Any idea what I can do? or should I start another question?

Comment: Did you try the second snippet?

Comment: okay, created_at DESC, that works (obviously). thanks. I'm interested in the use of case in your last snippet but don't understand what the "then 0 else 1" actually achieves. How does it work if you don't mind? I know case statements generally but don't get this syntax with 0,1 etc

Comment: @Michael: here it is in formatted form. Should be self-explaining. http://paste2.org/p/1936613 (1 and 0 switched places, so Canada will be below all other records).

Comment: The case trick creates a "virtual" column where all Canadian records have value 0 and other records have 1. Then this column is used for sorting. Zeroes come before ones and, therefore, Canada before all other records.